# Oracle SQL compare aggregated lines

Tags: sql, oracle

Kind of stuck in relatively simple SQL...

Could someone propose some code for retrieving the GroupID for aggregated lines (group by GroupID) whose aValue is  different ?
For example in the below table I'd need to get GroupID '4' as the 2 Items with in the same group (4) have different aValue

```
GroupId ItemID  aValue
4       19      Hello 
4       20      Hello1
5       78      Hello5
5       86      Hello5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `having` clause and look at the count of distinct values:

```
-- CTE for your sample data
with your_table (groupid, itemid, avalue) as (
  select 4, 19, 'Hello' from dual
  union all select 4, 20, 'Hello1' from dual
  union all select 5, 78, 'Hello5' from dual
  union all select 5, 86, 'Hello5' from dual
)
select groupid
from your_table
group by groupid
having count(distinct avalue) > 1;

   GROUPID
----------
         4
```

If you actually also want to see the individual values, you can use an analytic count in a subquery and filter that with `where` instead of `having`:

```
-- CTE for your sample data
with your_table (groupid, itemid, avalue) as (
  select 4, 19, 'Hello' from dual
  union all select 4, 20, 'Hello1' from dual
  union all select 5, 78, 'Hello5' from dual
  union all select 5, 86, 'Hello5' from dual
)
select groupid, itemid, avalue
from (
  select groupid, itemid, avalue,
    count(distinct avalue) over (partition by groupid) as value_count
  from your_table
)
where value_count > 1;

   GROUPID     ITEMID AVALUE
---------- ---------- ------
         4         19 Hello 
         4         20 Hello1
```

Comment: Thanks very much Alex.. your first suggestion is more than enough..I totally missed the having / distinct approach...

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as :

```
select GroupId
from table t
group by GroupId
having min(aValue) <> max(aValue);
```

However, if you want all `columns/expression` then you can use `EXISTS`

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1  
              from table t1 
              where t1.GroupId = t.GroupId and 
                    t1.avalue <> t.avalue
             );
```